# Passing data from UICollectionView to a new ViewController with segue in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, segue

I am trying to pass data to a new ViewController from CollectionView cell when is selected. I have 2 collection views on my HomeViewController using switch method. Everything is displayed proper and when I load the app the images in the collection views show. The problem is when I select a image the app breaks. The interesting part is that NOT always happens. Sometimes will work and sometime it does't. This is with the simulator. When I connect my actual iPhone works fine without breaking. Also, the view Controller I am passing the data has table view with sections and rows. This is my code:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, SWRevealViewControllerDelegate,    UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var hoodsCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var cuisineCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var hoodsArray = ["marina", "embac-1", "mission-1", "nbeach-1", "nob-1", "rhill-1", "ZHood-1"]
var cuisinesArray = ["marina", "embac-1", "mission-1", "nbeach-1", "nob-1", "rhill-1", "ZHood-1"] 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    hoodsCollectionView.dataSource = self
    cuisineCollectionView.dataSource = self

    hoodsCollectionView.delegate = self
    cuisineCollectionView.delegate = self
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch collectionView {

    case self.hoodsCollectionView:
        return self.hoodsArray.count

    case self.cuisineCollectionView:
        return self.cuisinesArray.count

    default:
        return 0
    }
}


 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    switch collectionView {


    case self.hoodsCollectionView:

        let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellHoods", for: indexPath) as! RestaurnatCollectionViewCell

        myCell.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        myCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 166/255, green: 166/255, blue: 166/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        myCell.layer.borderWidth = 0.7

        myCell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: hoodsArray[indexPath.row])


        return myCell

    case self.cuisineCollectionView:

        let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellCuisine", for: indexPath) as! RestaurnatCollectionViewCell

        myCell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: cuisinesArray[indexPath.row])

        return myCell

    default:
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}



   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {


    switch collectionView {

    case self.hoodsCollectionView:

        if let myCell = hoodsCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {


        performSegue(withIdentifier: "cellHoods", sender: myCell)


    }

    case self.cuisineCollectionView:

    if let myCell = cuisineCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "cuisineHoods", sender: myCell)


        }

    default:
        break
    }


}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


 if let indexPath = hoodsCollectionView.indexPath(for: sender as! RestaurnatCollectionViewCell) {

        if segue.identifier == "cellHoods" {

          let vc: HoodsViewController = segue.destination as! HoodsViewController

            vc.hoodsTest = hoodsArray[indexPath.row]


            }

    }

    if let indexPath = cuisineCollectionView.indexPath(for: sender as! RestaurnatCollectionViewCell) {

        if segue.identifier == "cuisineHoods" {

            let vc: CuisinesViewController = segue.destination as! CuisinesViewController

            vc.cuisineTest = cuisinesArray[indexPath.row]
        }
    }

  }

}
```

I am using segue.identifier to pass the data. My HomeViewController is connected in Storyboard to HoodsViewController and CuisinesViewController.
In HoodsViewController I have a `var hoodsTest = String()` and same in CuisinesViewController: `var cuisineTest = String()`
When I select a image passes the data and prints the name of the picture with `print(hoodTest)`.
Also I am using RestaurnatCollectionViewCell where I have:

```
@IBOutlet var myImage: UIImageView!
```

When the app breaks and give me error takes me to the HoodsViewController.
Same applies for CuisinesViewController if selected.

[image: Error snapshot]
[image: Error snapshot2]

```
cell.hoodLabel.text = self.filteredRestaurants[indexPath.section].restaurants[indexPath.row].name
```

I will appreciate any suggestions and ideas.I am new to Xcode and trying to learn. 
**As I said the crazy part is that sometime works and other doesn't in simulator. Always work when I connect the phone!**
Thanks again in advance for your help and understanding!

Comment: pls, put the code where filteredRestaurants is filled

Comment: why are you sending the cell in the sender  ?

Comment: @Farid I am passing data to HoodsViewController where I have I TableView populated with sections and rows. What are you suggesting?